# Facebook app invitation iOS SDK can't display the Invitation VC

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, cocoa-touch

So this's my code for app invite :

```
private func inviteFriends() {

    let content = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
    content.appLinkURL = URL(string: "...")
    content.appInvitePreviewImageURL    = URL(string: "...")
    FBSDKAppInviteDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: nil)
}
```

This code works fine but if I try to add the promotional code like this  :

```
private func inviteFriends() {

    let content = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
    content.appLinkURL = URL(string: "...")
    content.appInvitePreviewImageURL    = URL(string: "...")
    content.promotionCode = "preview"
    content.promotionText = "Use the *preview* code to unlock the app"
    FBSDKAppInviteDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: nil)
}
```

The the invite VC is not shown any more (the function is called but nothing is showing). What did I missed here ?

Comment: Have you tried initializing a FBSDKAppInviteDialog object and then calling show on that?

Comment: No i just tried to follow this  : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that I've used special character like `*` so removing it make the app works fine my final code is like this :

```
private func inviteFriends() {

    let content = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
    content.appLinkURL = URL(string: "...")
    content.appInvitePreviewImageURL    = URL(string: "...")
    content.promotionCode = "preview"
    content.promotionText = "Use the preview code to unlock the app"
    FBSDKAppInviteDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: nil)
}
```